# Php fails to update Date in MySQL table via HTML form

Tags: php, html, mysql, date

I cannot solve this seemingly simply problem. I have an HTML form posting to a php file which works perfectly well. However, when I post a date value from HTML to php the MySQL database updates all the required fields except the date which still shows as 0000-00-00. When I change the php variable to CURDATE() it works OK however, I do not require the current date but the date I post from my HTML file. This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Credit Note Generator v.2</title>
<meta name="generator" content="">
</head>
<body>
<div id="space"><br></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="wb_Form1" style="position:absolute;left:210px;top:110px;width:530px;height:381px;z-index:4;">
<form name="cnote" method="post" action="cnote.php" id="cnote">
<input type="number" id="dupid" style="position:absolute;left:240px;top:31px;width:207px;height:20px;line-height:20px;z-index:0;" name="dupid" value="" required="required">
<input type="date" id="cndate" style="position:absolute;left:240px;top:81px;width:207px;height:20px;line-height:20px;z-index:1;" name="cndate" value="" required="required" >
<textarea name="cnreason" id="cnreason" style="position:absolute;left:240px;top:141px;width:202px;height:127px;z-index:2;" rows="6" cols="24" required="required"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Generate" style="position:absolute;left:220px;top:310px;width:132px;height:47px;z-index:3;">
```

The input date I am passing from this HTML to php is:

```
<input type="date" id="cndate" style="position:absolute;left:240px;top:81px;width:207px;height:20px;line-height:20px;z-index:1;" name="cndate" value="" required="required" >
```

My php file (I am only including the relevant part) reads as follows:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);


$con = mysql_connect("192.168.10.223","user","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("BMS", $con);

$pass = $_POST["dupid"]; 
$cnotes = $_POST["cnreason"];
$cndatepost = $_POST["cndate"];
$cndate2 = strtotime($cndatepost);
$cndate = date('Y-m-d',$cndate2); 





//get highest
$sqlgethighest = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(CN_No) FROM Main_Data_Table");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlgethighest);
$cnoteno=($row['MAX(CN_No)'])+1;


$sql="INSERT INTO Main_Data_Table (ID, Name, Surname, TitleID, NationalityID, 
Age, AgentID, `Course Start`, `Course End`, CourseTypeID, `Rate per unit`, 
`Arrival Date`, `Departure Date`, `Arrival Time`, `Departure Time`, `Arrival Flight`, 
`Departure Flight`, AccommodationID, HostFamilyID, `Rate per night`, TransferId, 
`Material Fee`, `Total Units Booked`, `Reg Fee`, BoardBasisID, `Ref Fee Acc`, 
Notes, Notes2, DateofCanx, ReasonforCanx, HFXId, old_Invoice_number, LevelID, 
Hide, Alloc_CodeAMID, Alloc_CodePMID, Lunch, Binder, `Audio CD`, `CD-ROM/Web`, 
Tours, PromoMat, TrfFee, Settle_Bill, Commission, Pay_Local, Settle_Bill_rcpt, 
Pay_on_AC, Pay_on_AC_amt, Pay_on_AC_rcpt, Deposit, SageExportNo, Invoice_number,
TrfRateCode, `Extra Commission`, F56, F57, HOT_CONF, Room_type_ID, Invoice_Date,
CN_Date, CN_No, Passport_No, DOB, CN_Presence, Corresp_CN) 
SELECT NULL, Name, Surname, TitleID, NationalityID, Age, AgentID, `Course Start`, 
`Course End`, CourseTypeID, `Rate per unit`, `Arrival Date`, `Departure Date`, 
`Arrival Time`, `Departure Time`, `Arrival Flight`, `Departure Flight`, 
AccommodationID, HostFamilyID, `Rate per night`, TransferId, `Material Fee`, 
`Total Units Booked`, `Reg Fee`, BoardBasisID, `Ref Fee Acc`, CONCAT('Ref Invoice number: ', Invoice_number, ' ', '$cnotes'), Notes2, 
DateofCanx, ReasonforCanx, HFXId, old_Invoice_number, LevelID, Hide, 
Alloc_CodeAMID, Alloc_CodePMID, Lunch, Binder, `Audio CD`, `CD-ROM/Web`, 
Tours, PromoMat, TrfFee, 0, Commission, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, TrfRateCode, 
`Extra Commission`, F56, F57, HOT_CONF, Room_type_ID, NULL, $cndate, $cnoteno, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL 
from Main_Data_Table WHERE ID='$pass'";
```

My var_dump correctly displays: string(10) "2015-02-26" for the string $cndate which is the value I am trying to pass but for some reason it is still updating as 0000-00-00.

Thanks

Comment: Please check the value of date in the query is it ok in it using print it if it ok then run directly in server is it update ok  when you directly update it

Comment: That is one hell of a table. You should seriously consider splitting it up into smaller tables. Also, you should *check for MySQL errors*. It is a waste of our time to comb through your code, when you could figure it out for yourself. You should also not use the `mysql_*` functions; they have been deprecated for years. Use something like `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: What type of column is date in db? if its datetime or timestamp , then change it varchar.

Comment: check datatype of field for compatibility with value which is being inserted.

Comment: 1.- Design a good data model, not just a flat one with no relations at all
2.- Use PDO functions to deal with your data
3.- The same way you would not store a float as a varchar, do not store dates as varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While inserting  put $cndate in single quote  '$cndate'.

Also do check data type of cndate field

Answer (score 1):

Database wont be able store `date` type data from html...you need to change your `date` entry of your database to `varchar` to be able to store html `date` type..