# Reactjs - date type field does not update MYSQL date column of type DATE

Tags: mysql, reactjs

I have the following code that does not update the Database "date" column when the field type in MYSQL is DATE.

When I change the column type to VARCHAR the date gets updated. I need to keep the column as DATE so that I can perform calculations such as determine Age.

I think the question to ask is how to get the value from DateInput and update the date column? Looks like I may need some conversion before passing value to database but I am not sure. Appreciate any help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
...
import DateInput from '../others/input/datePicker'
...
class EditProfile extends Component {
  state = {
...
...
  changeDOB = () => {
    this.setState({ age: document.getElementById("datePicker").value })
  }
...
  render() {
    let {
...
...
  } = this.state
                <DateInput
                  type="date"
                  value={age}
                  onChange={this.changeDOB}
                  placeholder="Birth Date"
                  className="my2"
                  id="datePicker"
                />
...
```

Comment: accessing value from DOM is antipattern in react; there is nothing adout updating DB in this code; you have to match date formats

Comment: @xadm - I dont know what you mean. Do you know why VARCAR updates and DATE does not ?Thats the question.

Comment: `date in js != date in sql`

Comment: @xadm I know that, Thats why I asked the question here to get an answer or idea on how to fix my problem. Also this is not `date in js`. The date comes from html `field type date`

Comment: ... and still you wrote nothing about server code

Comment: What format is your date currently? What is the value of `this.state.age` after you select a date? What does your `DateInput` component look like?

Comment: @thirtydot - After I select a date and click update profile - `2018-09-14` is the value updated in redux state. My date input is a simple date type `https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_date.asp`..  As mentioned in my question, when my column in MYSQL is VARCHAR the same code works and updates the database. So I think the state is updated but not getting written to column of type DATE.

Comment: check date format for your SQL DB in docs (may vary), try to update it from DB browser/util (maybe STR_TO_DATE() is needed) and convert value to match this requirements. VARCHAR is updated because doesn't have to match any requirements, value for DATE can be ignored when wrongly formatted.

Comment: try also `changeDOB = (e) => { this.setState({ age: e.target.value }) }`

Comment: I tried these options but did not work. Based on the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778878/php-fails-to-update-date-in-mysql-table-via-html-form I gave up and will use VARCHAR but age calculations with date in VARCHAR will need extra code

Comment: There's no way you want to use `VARCHAR` to hold a date. You will regret it, and the next guy to look at your code will not be happy. You should try a bit harder to fix this the right way, unless you literally have no time.

Comment: What is the value of `dateofbirth` in your server-side code (just before `db.query`)?

Comment: I am able to calculate age as well with VARCHAR using a simple function. But I agree with you, I dont like that it is not a DATE.

Comment: @thirtydot - I added an image showing the redux state after submit was clicked.

Comment: What does `console.log(dateofbirth)` give you above `db.query`?

Comment: @thirtydot - Added couple more screenshots showing everything. Thanks

Comment: Is your column called `age` or `dateofbirth`? In your query you have `UPDATE users SET ... dateofbirth=? ...`. But your column appears to be called `age` in the database, according to one of the latest screenshots.

Comment: @thirtydot - It is consistently called "age". I did not want to confuse in the question so I was hiding the fact that my DOB column is called age and added `dateofbirth` in the question here.. I was initially planning to make users enter their age but later decided to calculate it using DOB

Comment: You need to get your code to show the actual executed query. Look at the snippet of code here labelled "This escaping allows you to do neat things like this": https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers. (Make the `console.log(query.sql);` thing work with your code).

Answer (score 0):

The date value that comes from html input date field is not compatible with the date in MYSQL. The MYSQL documentation suggests that the date format is UTC. You have to perform some updates to the date before passing it onto the table.
VARCHAR works for you because it does not need to fulfill any format requirements to be updated in the database.